# create method linq query for assigning values to viewmodel class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Model classes ::

```
public class MappedModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int MappedId { get; set; }
        public int MappedType { get; set; }
        public string MappedDate { get; set; }
        public decimal MappedAmount { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public ProjectModels Project { get; set; } 
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SchoolId")]
        public SchoolModels School { get; set; }
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    }
    
public class ProjectModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }        
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }        
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }            
    }
```

ViewModel class::

```
public class MappedViewModels
    {
        public int MappedType { get; set; }
        public string MappedDate { get; set; }
        public decimal MappedAmount { get; set; }

        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        
        public decimal ProjectAllocatedAmount { get; set; } // assigned amount for each project

        public decimal RemainingAmount { get; set; }  // remaining amount from the project amount that can be allocated


        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}
```

I have omitted the school model class since it include only Name and Id.

`MappedModels` is used to assign project amount to different schools. Users have to select School name and Project Name from dropdowns. Then allocate project amount to that respective school.
Before allocating amount, I want to show users the actual Project Amount and the remaining amount for that Project.

Lets say example data in ProjectModels `{1, MEEG203, 500000}`

Supose this ProjectId is already mapped for a school with amount 300000.

Now if a user selects same ProjectId for allocating amount to another school, I want to show that:
ProjectAllocatedAmount = 500000
RemainingAmount = 500000 - 300000 = 200000

I have already calculated the RemainingAmount assigned in variable `all`.

But this query is returning null value, why is it so? I am unable to understand what is wrong with this query.

```
public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectId)
        {
// other code blocks ommitted...
        
var result = db.Mappeds.Include(p => p.Project)
                .Where(p => p.ProjectId == ProjectId).Select(x => new MappedViewModels()

            {

                ProjectName = x.Project.ProjectName,

                ProjectAllocatedAmount = x.Project.Amount,

                SchoolName = "",

                MappedAmount = 0,

                RemainingAmount = x.Project.Amount - all

            }).ToList().LastOrDefault();
            
return View(result);            
            }
```

Comment: one thing I can think of is there are no records which are matching with the `projectId` that you are passing

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Actually there was no row that have that `projectId`. So I changed the logic using `if...else` statement. Thank You!!!

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty Can you please help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502779/insert-data-using-view-model-class . Thank You!!!