# insert data using view model class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Model class::

```
public class MappedModels
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MappedId { get; set; }
        public int MappedType { get; set; }
        public decimal MappedAmount { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public ProjectModels Project { get; set; } 
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    }
```

View Model Class::

```
public class MappedViewModels
    {
        public int MappedType { get; set; }
        public decimal MappedAmount { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        
        // these two fields only in MappedViewModels for calculation purpose
        public decimal ProjectAllocatedAmount { get; set; } 
        public decimal RemainingAmount { get; set; }  
}
```

I have created the `Create.cshtml` page for `MappedModels` using MappedViewModels. Now when I try to submit the form, I am getting error::

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'myapp.Models.MappedModels', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'myapp.ViewModels.MappedViewModels'.
```

My Create controller method::

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MappedId,MappedType,MappedAmount,ProjectId")] MappedModels mappedModels)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Mappeds.Add(mappedModels);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(mappedModels);
}
```

If I change the method to `public ActionResult Create( MappedViewModels mappedModels)`, then getting error in `db.Mappeds.Add(mappedModels)`

I have to use the fields of `MappedViewModels` in `public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectId)`.

Also, my `MappedViewModels` does not contain attribute `MappedId`, if I keep it there (MappedViewModels) also how can `MappedId` be **auto increment**.

So how to insert data using `MappedViewModels` to `MappedModels`?

As suggested in solution I tried ::

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MappedType,MappedAmount,ProjectId")] MappedViewModels model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var dbMappedModel = new MappedModels
        {
          MappedType = model.MappedType,
          MappedAmount = model.MappedAmount,
          ProjectId = model.ProjectId
        }

        db.Mappeds.Add(dbMappedModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(mappedModels);
}
```

But getting error `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`. It is causing because of Project class where there are multiple required fields. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you post what are the `EntityValidationErrors` that you are seeing? use this post to see the validation errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert#answers-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your action logic as below

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MappedType,MappedAmount,ProjectId")] MappedViewModels model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // when you add to the context, create a new MappedModels object
        // You need not to worry about the MappedId, it will be auto incremented
        var dbMappedModel = new MappedModels
        {
          MappedType = model.MappedType,
          MappedAmount = = model.MappedAmount,
        
          Project = new ProjectModels { ... }
        }

        db.Mappeds.Add(dbMappedModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(mappedModels);
}
```

What is the use of `[Bind(Include = "MappedType,MappedAmount,ProjectId")]` I don't think that is required. I never used it.

Comment: Please clarify `Project = new ProjectModels { ... }`. Thank You!!!

Comment: If you also want to insert records to `Project` you can assign the values as above. else don't assign any values to it, it will be `null` and no record will be inserted to `Project` table

Comment: But I am getting required field error while trying to insert data because of this `Project`. There are multiple required fields in `Project` class.

Comment: Where are you getting the required field error? just give `Project = null` and try once.